# why can i not apply loop property inside specific property parameter in animejs

Tags: javascript, css-animations, anime.js

I am trying to animate two blocks using animejs, when using translateX I cannot apply loop inside it.

```
  {
    value: 300,
    duration: 1000,
    delay: 500,
    easing: 'easeInOutSine'
  },
  {
    value: 0,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'easeInOutSine',
    direction: 'alternate', 
    loop: true
   }
],
```

This does not work. I could have used loops without using specific parameters but its necessary to introduce delay in the start, otherwise the animations start even before the content is loaded (I put the script tag in the end still it's happening), and if I try to use loop here then after each round it will continue the delay.

Comment: Hey, while editing your question I noticed you forgot a comma after `direction: 'alternate'`.  I don't know if this is related to your problem. You must have seen an error in the console though!

Comment: yups i did too now 
but thats not an issue its my mistake i forgot to put comma here but in the editor i have it with the comma but still not working

Comment: Did you try to put your code in a `window.onload` event handler?

Answer (score 1):

`direction`, `loop`, and `autoplay` are animation parameters, not property parameters. They apply to the entire animation, and it's not really clear what it would even mean to alternate on just one keyframe, for example. Loop and autoplay are confusing in the same way.

If you want it to loop between those two positions, just put it outside of the keyframes. But looping includes replaying that delay at the beginning. You should try waiting for a DOMContentReady event or similar before launching your animations, otherwise you could create the animation with `autoplay: false`, then do `setTimeout(animation, 300)` to delay starting it without inserting a delay into the animation.